# ReactJS: button (span) visual should re-render and change when clicked, but doesnt (using setState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a young developer, trying to create my first website using reactjs, and working on a custom navbar. I would like the button that i press in the navbar, to change color once pressed, while all of the others remain the same color, but my code doesnt seem to work. I'm using useState to control values for the classNames (visuals) of the buttons. My code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container, Col, Row, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../App.css';

const NavButtons = () => {

    const [navbuttons, setnavbuttons] = useState([
        {id: 0, urlAdd: "/", name: "FORSIDE", show: "navlit"},
        {id: 1, urlAdd: "/priser", name: "PRISER", show: "navlif"},
        {id: 2, urlAdd: "/tilmeldning", name: "TILDMELDING", show: "navlif"},
        {id: 3, urlAdd: "/kontakt", name: "KONTAKT", show: "navlif"},
        {id: 4, urlAdd: "/faq", name: "FAQ", show: "navlif"}
    ]);

    let handleChange = index => {
        let currentbuttons = navbuttons;
        for(let i=0; i<currentbuttons.length; i++){
            currentbuttons[i].show = i == index? "natlit":"natlif";
        }
        setnavbuttons(currentbuttons);
        console.log(currentbuttons[index].show)
    }

    let history = useHistory();

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="navul">
            {navbuttons.map(navbut => 
                <span 
                    className={navbut.show}
                    onClick={() => {
                        handleChange(navbut.id);
                        history.push(navbut.urlAdd);
                    }}
                    ><p/>{navbut.name}
                </span>)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NavButtons;
```

When i press the buttons, the state changes, but the buttons dont seem to re-render. If you could me what im doing wrong, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

handleChange needs to be fixed so it doesn't change the existing state, but adds new objects in the old state's place.

```
let handleChange = index => {
    let currentbuttons = [...navbuttons];
    for(let i=0; i<currentbuttons.length; i++){
        currentbuttons[i] = {...currentbuttons[i], show: i === index? "natlit":"natlif"};
    }
    setnavbuttons(currentbuttons);
}
```